# Ensuring memory visibility with builder/factory pattern

Tags: java, thread-safety, volatile, synchronized, memory-visibility

The following class:

```
class Pizza {

    Ingredients ingredients;
    Price price;

    public setIngredients(Ingredients ing) {
        if (ingredients != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        ingredients = ing;
        return this;
    }

    public setPrice(Price p) {
        if (price != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        price = p;
        return this;
    }

}
```

could be used in a builder pattern, and after it has been built, it's *effectively immutable*, because each property can be set only once. That is:

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza().setIngredients(something).setPrice(somethingelse);
```

However, `Pizza` is not thread safe: there are no guarantees that thread B sees the ingredients that were set into it by the thread A. There are some ways to fix it:

- Make members `final`. But then you can't use a builder pattern.
- Synchronize access to members. But this seems like waste, because they're written only once ever.
- Make them `volatile`. Feels waste, like synchronization.
- Use `AtomicReference`.
- Etc.?

My question is, what is the best way to tell the JVM that a class member won't change after some method has been called? Should I just synchronize access to it, and trust that the JVM will optimize the lock away? It just feels waste, because I *know* that the member *should* behave like it's `final` after it's set. Aren't there any better solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builder pattern usually means that builder is a separate object. In this case you can make fields of the object being built `final`, and initialize them in constructor called by the builder object:

```
Pizza pizza = 
    new PizzaBuilder()
        .setIngredients(something)
        .setPrice(somethingelse)
        .build();
```

Alternatively, you can ensure safe publication of the `Pizza` object. Note that safe publication idioms are applied to the field that contains a reference to the object being published, not to the fields of that object itself. For example, if `pizza` is a field of some object, you can make it `volatile` or synchronize access to it - it would ensure safe publication of `Pizza` object assigned to that field.

Answer (score 1):

If the member values are never meant to change, the a better pattern would be to have a `Pizza` constructor that takes as its parameters `Ingredients` and `Price`, and have no setter methods on the object at all.  Really it is not useful to have a `setSomething()` method that throws an exception after the first time it is called.

Consider how the `String` class works.  Once you have instantiated a `String` with some text, the text value cannot be changed.  The only way to get a `String` with a different value is to construct a new one.  It seems like that is what you want here.

Using this pattern also avoids the synchronization issue.

Comment: The idea of `setSomething()` method that throws an exception after the first time it is called is to enforce the effective immutability property of that member. Of course everything could be `final`, and then you have a constructor that takes 20 arguments in, but avoiding that is one point of the builder pattern AFAIK.

Comment: But in this case you only have 2 arguments, not 20.  Though if that's you concern, then I suggest axtavt's answer.  You can have a `PizzaBuilder` class with setters that _always_ work, and a `Pizza` instance is not constructed until after `build()` (or personally, I would use `toPizza()`) is called.  So the only place that needs to know about the `Pizza` constructor is in `PizzaBuilder`, and everyone else just needs to know that "to get a `Pizza` I should use a `PizzaBuilder`".